# Define module with javascript string in SystemJS

Tags: systemjs

I'm trying to create a SystemJS module from a string of es6 code (I know...  but I've got my reasons). How would I go about doing that?

For example, with a configuration that looks something like:

```
System.config({
  paths: {
    'jquery': "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js",
  },
  transpiler: 'plugin-babel',
  meta: { ...
```

I'm trying to

```
const javascriptString = `
    import $ from 'jquery';

    export function doSomething() {
      ...
    };
`;

System.module(javascriptString)
  .then(m => {
    m.doSomething();
  });
```

I do see a few (dated?) references to a `System.module` method: [here](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html#sec_module-loader-api) and [here](http://2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html#importing-modules-and-loading-scripts). But this doesn't seem to be implemented by SystemJS.

How could I go about do this?

Thanks.